# Session locking nonstop other sessions

Tags: sql-server-2014

so Suddenly we have a NULL session locking everything else.

[image]

the rows goes on if the server are left for some minutes running.
`DBCC INPUTBUFFER` returns "No Event".

`sp_who2` says `background,unknown token`.

It doesn't show on sp_who3. I have no idea how to track this.

is this known? I thought it would be the db startup session but I can't find the info if it is or not.

I can't even open database list, because the session gets locked.

can't failover dbs, or set sync/async. that session is locking everything.

it can't be killed !

Comment: Do you see any errors in SQL logs? If this is an AvailabilityGroup, how does the cluster state look like? What's the state of the databases if you query sys.databases?

Comment: What does [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) say about it?